# Create column with Year and autoincrement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, auto-increment

i want to know if is possible to create a table with a Column which got a autoincrement with the number of the year in front if ( Format: YYYY## ):

```
CRATE TABLE "Example"(
[Number] autoincrement(YYYY##),
[Text] nvarchar(30)
)
```

how has the column 'number' to look like? ist it even possible?

thanks!

**Part 2:**

The number behind the year should start from 0 after every year.

Example output:

2013-01

2013-02

2013-03

2014-01

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Microsft SQL Server is the DataBase Management System, the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is the tool used to work with Microsoft SQL Server :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Computed Columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx)

For example:

```
 CREATE TABLE T 
    (
        ID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL, 
        DateField datetime DEFAULT (getdate()),
        DateIDChar AS CAST(YEAR(DateField) AS Varchar)+'-'+CAST(ID as VARCHAR),
        DateIDInt AS YEAR(DateField) * 10000+ID,
        SampleField varchar(100)
    );
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ac3c/1)</kbd>

Here:

- `ID` is a base autoincremented field
- `DateField` is a DateTime part with current date as default
- `DateIDChar` - example computed field formatted as a `varchar`
- `DateIDId` - example computed field formatted as a `int`

Comment: Dude, it's like the best answer I could get :D Thank u very much

Comment: can u do one more cast on ID ? would be awesome if it begins from 0 after every yeahr

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot do this with the autoincrement column. You could, instead, have an additional column with the day of creation of the record. Then, when you want to output the column with the autoincrement, you can format the output according to your especifications.

i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE "Example" (
[Number] autoincrement(YYYY##),
[Text] nvarchar(30),
[CreatedDate] datetime
) 

-- output
select convert(varchar(4), year(CreatedDate)) + convert(varchar, Number)
```

Hope this helps